# vsftpd limit users to /home/user/minecraft

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

So using vsftpd I want to lock a user to `/home/theirname/Minecraft`. I can't change their home directory because a program I'm using(McMyAdmin) will try to reinstall itself but I don't want them having access to the programs configs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tutorial would seem to be what you're looking for, titled: [Setup Virtual Users and Directories in VSFTPD](http://howto.gumph.org/content/setup-virtual-users-and-directories-in-vsftpd/).

*excerpt*

In `/etc/vsftpd.conf`.

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
write_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd
pam_service_name=vsftpd
guest_enable=YES
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/var/www/sites/$USER
chroot_local_user=YES
hide_ids=YES
```

You'll likely need to customize this slightly based on what your needs are. You'll want to change the `local_root` line for starters:

```
local_root=/home/$USER/Minecraft
```